# How can I load data from url promise before rendering html page in Ionic 2/3?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, servicestack

In my case I have one ionic page showing the selected items in different templates. for each item type I have settings object that can be fetched from server using ngOnint after item selected, I rendering the html depends on these settings. for example I show/hide some component using *ngIf.

the problem is in html file the settings object is undefined.
how can I get the settings object before rendering html.
note: Im using servicestack web services.

```
      <div class="user-details">
        <ion-segment class="user-content-segment" [(ngModel)]="display">
            <ion-segment-button value="description">
                Açıklama
            </ion-segment-button>

            <ion-segment-button *ngIf="settings.Commmon.UseMenuList" value="prices">
                Fiyatlar
            </ion-segment-button>
            <ion-segment-button value="location">
                Konum
            </ion-segment-button>
            <ion-segment-button value="reviews">
                Yorumlar
            </ion-segment-button>
        </ion-segment>
    </div>
```

the ts file

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
            public navParams: NavParams, private postApi: PostAPI,
            public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public alerCtrl: AlertController) {
    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create();
    this.post = navParams.get('post');
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.postApi.GetPostTypeSetting(this.post.PostTypeId).then(res => {
        this.settings = res;
        console.log(res);
    });
    this.postApi.GetPostDetail(this.post.PostId).then(res => {
        this.postDetail = res;
        console.log(res);
    });

    this.postApi.GetCategoryDetail(1, 1).then(res2 => {

    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a standard value for your variable. `*ngIf` will constantly check if the condition has changed. So you define something like this:

```
public settings: object = {
    Common: {
        UseMenuList: false
    }
};
```

At the moment you get an error, because you trying to access a variable thats not defined, because your api request is asynchronous. So just define a default value (whether true or false) and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

in Ionic you can use `ionViewWillEnter()` function for this purpose

Comment: the problem still the same, it says that the settings object is undefined. I have add this code to will enter method     ionViewWillEnter() {
        this.nBar.setBackButtonText("");
        this.postApi.GetPostTypeSetting(this.post.PostTypeId).then(res => {
            this.settings = res;
            console.log(res);
        });
    }

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are looking for is **ionViewCanEnter()**

> Runs before the view can enter. This can be used as a sort of "guard" in authenticated views where you need to check permissions before the view can enter

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

```
ionViewCanEnter(): boolean {

  this.postApi.GetPostTypeSetting(this.post.PostTypeId).then(res => {
      this.settings = res;
      console.log(res);

      this.postApi.GetPostDetail(this.post.PostId).then(res2 => {
          this.postDetail = res2;
          console.log(res2);

          this.postApi.GetCategoryDetail(1, 1).then(res3 => {
               console.log(res3);
               return true;
          });
      });
  });
}
```